# How can I make sudo forget the password automatically after one command?

Tags: bash, sudo

My problem is the following: I want to edit a file that is only readable by root. That's why I use

```
sudo vim ~/thefile
```

I could type

```
sudo -K
```

after exiting vim, but I was hoping that there's an option or something that makes sudo forget the password automatically. Of course I thought about editing the sudoers file and setting the timeout to 0, but I don't want to change the settings in general. I also found nothing in the manpage...

Is there a way to do this?

If interesting: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and bash.

Comment: As a workaround, try `function sudok () { sudo "$@"; sudo -K; }`

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me!! Where would I save this to make it last?

Comment: And: why didn't you post it as answer?

Comment: You should put that function into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`. This will make it only available to your user account which sounds like what you want. If you want every user on the system to have access to `sudok` then put it in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that information. I forgot about the bashrc! Now how should I get this thread solved? Mark Plotnick should write this stuff here as an answer, shouldn't he?

Comment: Good. I added it as an answer.

Comment: Use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo vim`. You don't need the editor to run as root.

Comment: Thanks for the sudoedit hint, I didn't know of that. But I think in my case it doesn't fit: I don't want any temporary copies to be created that are readable by the current user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an option to sudo that will do exactly what you want, but you can make a shell function that will create a new command `sudok`, which will run the sudo command and then have sudo remove its cached credentials.

```
function sudok () { sudo "$@"; sudo -K; }
```

Add that line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to make it permanent.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you just want `sudo`'s little-`k` option,

```
sudo -k vim ~/thefile
```

which is documented to completely ignore your cachefile:

> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may require
>       a password, this option will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached
>       credentials.  As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one
>       is required by the security policy) and will not update the user's
>       cached credentials.

Comment: I tried to make this clear two times already: I don't want the shell to forget the credentials that are already there! I want the shell to forget the credentials (that I might have to type or that I might not need to type because they're already there) **AFTER** the actions in vim!! The answer of Mark_Plotnick does what I searched for...

Answer (score 2):

See [`man sudoers`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html); a `timestamp_timeout` setting is described there. Set it to `0` to make `sudo` always prompt for a password.

Comment: That's what I meant by "I don't want to change the settings in general". I'd like to keep the timeout as it is!

Comment: Do you mean that you'd only want to change the setting for yourself? Or only for one particular command? I suppose there's `sudoedit -k` just for that; make a convenient alias. I suspect that you can even make calling `sudo vim` by a particular user to use `timestamp_timeout = 0`, but I did not try that and cannot guarantee it would work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad english here, I'll try to make it clear: I want the shell to not remember my password after I exit vim. And I don't want to change user based settings like the timeout because I like the way everything works. So as you said, I'd like to change the settings for one command only...