# How to temporarily disable sudo credentials timestamp timeout?

Tags: scripting, sudo

Let's say, I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo command1
command2
sudo command3
```

I don't want to run `command2` as root, so I won't run the script itself with `sudo`. Therefore, as soon as I execute the script, `sudo command1` asks for my password. Unfortunately, `command2` takes about 2 hours to complete. So the sudo credentials timestamp timed out and when the script reaches `sudo command3`, I'm prompted for the password again.

I don't want to permanently disable the sudo credentials timestamp timeout altogether as described in https://superuser.com/a/149740 for example. I just want to disable the timeout temporarily, effectively keep the credentials for this one bash session until it ends.

Comment: Kick off a background job to run `sudo -v` every 5 minutes (e.g. `watch -n 600 sudo -v &`), for the duration of the `command2` execution.

Comment: @steve that's a good idea; you'd have to ensure that sudoers was configured with !requiretty, as it wouldn't have a tty in the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is a (backgrounded) busy-wait loop that refreshes the sudo timestamp, which you then kill when you no longer need `sudo` privileges. Here's a sample script; it runs `sleep 6` instead of your two-hour `command2` and runs visible `/bin/echo` commands instead of `command1` and `command2`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sudo /bin/echo command 1
while :; do sudo -v; sleep 1; done &
infiloop=$!
sleep 6
sudo /bin/echo command 3
kill "$infiloop"
```

For your actual script, I would recommend a looser loop:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sudo command1
while :; do sudo -v; sleep 59; done &
infiloop=$!
command2
sudo command3
kill "$infiloop"
```

Adjust the `sleep 59` to taste, depending on the existing `timestamp_timeout` setting in sudoers; I chose 59 just to demonstrate a choice you could make if the timestamp timeout was 60 seconds.

Comment: You can also use `trap` to ensure that the kill command is executed upon exiting the script.

Answer (score 4):

I must be missing something here, because the solution seems very obvious to me.

> I don't want to run `command2` as root, so I won't run the script itself with `sudo`.

But you can run the whole script with `sudo` without running `command 2` as root if you change the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
sudo -u ${SUDO_USER:-$USER} command2
command3
```

Comment: Why would I test it _without_ `sudo`? You didn't say you _needed_ to run it both with and without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

By **refreshing** credentials in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash


configurePermissions () {
    sudo -v
    refreshPermissions "$$" &
}


refreshPermissions () {
    local pid="${1}"

    while kill -0 "${pid}" 2> /dev/null; do
        sudo -v
        sleep 10
    done
}


configurePermissions
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be possible to combine [How can I make sudo forget the password automatically after one command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186816/how-can-i-make-sudo-forget-the-password-automatically-after-one-command) and [What's the purpose of using `sudo -S` explicitly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434759/whats-the-purpose-of-using-sudo-s-explicitly)

1. Read password from user, save it in environment variable
2. Run `sudo` with `-k` flag to ignore credentials so it will always prompt for the password
3. Pass the password via `stdin` into `sudo` with flag `-S`
4. Remove password environment variable

It might be useful for certain situations, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to store the user's password in an environment variable.